# How do I validate the Maven properties for plugin development?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Working on a simple Maven plugin that allows a user to substring some property that exists on the Maven Project.

How can I validate that the plugin has worked correctly in one of the IT tests? It should modify the I've got a verify.groovy but there doesn't seem to be much in scope. I would have thought the plugin tester would have access to all the Maven project stuff that was in memory during the build.

Here's the core code I want to be able to validate.

```java
String newValue;
if (substringEnd != -1 ) {
    newValue = project.getProperties().getProperty(propertyName)
        .substring(substringStart, substringEnd);
} else {
    newValue = project.getProperties().getProperty(propertyName)
        .substring(substringStart);
}
```

Comment: Sounds more like unit tests instead of an integration tests.

Comment: What about making a patch for the [build-helper-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/build-helper-maven-plugin) ? Or at least making a feature request for it?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm really just using this as an opportunity to teach myself plugin development.

Comment: Can you show the code...You do not check the existence of the propertyName here? And not if substringEnd is in a valid range?